# How to order Django objects by the attributes of their foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code:

```
from django.db import Models

class Model1(models.Model):
    #Attributes...


class Model2(models.Model):
    model1_foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(Model1, related_name='some_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My objective is to order the first item by the latest creation of their foreign keys. For example:

```
Today is September eighth
Model A is an instance of Model1 and has two models related to it via the foreign key, model B (created on September 5th) and model C (created on September 6th). Assume times don't matter here.
Model D is an instance of Model1 and has another two models related to it via a foreign key, E and F (Created on September 5th and 7th respectively).
```

Given access to a list of objects of Model1, such as Model1.objects.all, how can I order the models such that model D comes first (It has the latest Model2 object, created on september 7th).
Alternatively, what can I change to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Model1.objects.all().order_by('-model2__created')
```

In this code `model2` is the `related_query_name` of `model1_foreign_key`, which is the class name by default.